# From Windows OS to GitHub repository - install_github() wont work - maybe Rtools related

Tags: windows, r, github, ropensci

A: This is the project I've got in mind - (weblink) schamberlain.github.com/2012/10/rgbif-newfxns/

B: Here is their GitHub - https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif

C: My machine: i86-64bit, Windows 7, R. 2.15, RStudio 0.96.330

Following their instructions, I perform the following:

a) Download & Installation of Rtools 2.15 (weblink) cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

this step is plain sorcery to me, I am just following the instructions given in the "Windows toolset" appendix (weblink) cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset.

In the end I've got this nasty C:\Rtools folder in my system, and the PATH variables (no idea what this is) are set as the appendix suggest (as far as I can say).

b) in R: library(devtools)

c) in R: install_github("rgbif", "ropensci")

This will produce some notification output and ends in this [Error message](http://pastebin.com/sU3G54SJ) (its a pastebin.com snipet of the output).

I am not sure whether or not it is possible to help with the provided information. Also I am feeling there is something missing between (a) and (b) - b/c I can't see a package 'Rtools' afterwards in R - maybe thats how it's supposed to be, how should I know?

I should add: In my default library folder .../Documents/R/win-library/2.15 there IS afterwards an un-zipped folder "ropensci-rgbif-60c74ca" with all the needed files in it! But I can't access it from within R.

Comment: Do this instead. Download the zip file to the project. [direct link](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/zipball/master), then in R run `library(devtools)`, then run `install('/path/to/unzipped/folder')` and that should install. If not you can also email us at support@ropensci.org

Comment: @Maiasaura This leads to exactly the same Warning-, Error- & "Zusätzliche Warnmeldung" - messages as before. You mentioned it just implicite - just to be clear: I unzipped the file before the install() command.

Comment: Scott here, also from rOpenSci - I am getting a windows binary version up for the current github repo for rgbif.  Look out for that at github [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif)

Comment: The Windows binary is up on the repo site ( https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/downloads) try it out and let us know if it works or not.

Comment: Check your path variables, this sounds like the culprit. Make sure it's pointing to the version of R that you're expecting it to.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've been able to install this package. Now taxonsearch() doesn't work - probably b/c I am unable to load the GitHub-Version of "httr". It says it can't use the argument "as = text" from the content() function. So I changed in taxonsearch() the line with content() to text_content() - and now it works.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain but of course like that every other rgbif-function with the content() line in it will fail (like: taxonget, taxoncount, densitylist, etc.).

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I'm including the/my location of R as follows: "c:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64" in this x64-Folder are the R.exe and Rgui.exe located.

Comment: You don't need to set any paths with devtools - it will figure them out itself.

Comment: @hadley I gave it a try and did as described in my orig. question - just without editing the PATH. It fails with the ever-same Error-massage (see link in orig. question).

Comment: Hmmm. Did you run `has_devel()` to check that devtools is set up correctly?

Comment: @hadley has_devel() returns TRUE.

Comment: What does `C:\Users\zhch333\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIVuiOB/rgbif_0.1.0.tar.gz` look like?

Comment: @hadley I wonder if there is anything I can do in this package to allow either `text_content()`, `parsed_content()`, or `content()` depending on the users version of httr?

Comment: @hadley there are some "...\Temp\Rtmpxxxxxx\" folders (one actually contains "\ropensci-rgbif-4d2acde" and "\rs-graphics-xxxx"), but I cant find a "/rgbif_0.1.0.tar.gz"-file in any of them.

Comment: @Chrugel I will see if I can get up a version that will work for you soon, maybe just reverting back to RCurl, at least just on a branch on github for now.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I would love to see that! Anyway: I am very surprised (and overwhelmed) how dedicated & helpful you rOpenSci ppl are! I really didn't felt ok to bother you that much... hopefully this helps you at least to have an idea of a less talented "average" user. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Okay, rgbif using RCurl is up on the branch `withrcurl` at github [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/tree/withrcurl). Let me know if it works for you now. You shouldn't need to have httr at all for that branch

Comment: Now its up, try `install_github('rgbif', 'ropensci', ref="withrcurl")` then `library(rgbif)`

Comment: Actually, just decided to merge that `withrcurl` branch in to master, so you can just `install_github("rgbif","ropensci")`

Comment: I am sorry, but the `install_github()` still doesn't work. For me only the manual download of your binary version worked ([this](https://github.com/ropensci/rgbif/downloads) one) - but there I've got still the problem with `content()`.

Comment: Hooray - with the binary v. 0.1.1 everything works as expected!